# Send encrypted mail using GPG by command-line?

Tags: windows, email, windows-xp, command-line-interface, batch-file

A few days ago I asked about how I can secure email and many people advised me to use PGP tool, and I read about it and I use it.

Now I want to write a batch file to send encrypted email with attachments. I know how I can generate key, exchange key with other side and encrypt email with PGP mail but until now I don't know how I can integrate PGP tool with my mail and how I can send the encrypted email.

In other words, how can I send encrypted email that encrypts with PGP tool to other side by command line (batch file)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Many clients support an extension for PGP. You could use Enigmail with Thunderbird for instance.

Answer (score 0):

As an absolute last resort, you could install `cygwin` and then install `mutt`. You can do it all via a shell script (shell/bash also comes with cygwin).

See this thread for details:
http://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-529419-start-0.html

** Note ** There is probably a much better (more Windows-native) way of doing this on your system since you aren't running *nix. But if no other alternatives come up, this approach should work.

Answer (score 0):

If you can run Perl and PGP/GNUPG from the command line, then modifying part of this [PGP Form Mail](http://www.rsmarketing.com/pgp/) script may be of interest.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of [GnuPG frontends](http://www.gnupg.org/related_software/frontends.en.html) recommended on the GPG homepage, including sections for network interfaces, scripting interfaces and Windows-specific sofware.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to incorporate pgp into outlook 2007 using a combination of vbs and bat all together. It is a self contained folder. However, I was using pgp 6.5.8 to do this. The only issue with this process was it had extra space at the end of the CRLF. My work around was to attach the encrypted file to the MS outlook. Which was added in the script to attach the file automatically after it was encrypted. This script was built from ms dos and able to use in other email platforms.

.https://www.dropbox.com/s/jrper2dg0ij1j51/outlook_encrypt_pgp.bat